# Correct standard error and p-values for Bradley-Terry model applied to ranking data ("rank-breaking")

Tags: r, p-value, standard-error, clustered-standard-errors, bradley-terry-model

One way to analyze ranking data is to use the Bradley-Terry data by converting ranks to pairwise comparisons (e.g. a>b>c becomes a>b, b>c, a>c) This is called "rank-breaking" in the machine learning literature. (But it was proposed already by Thurstone in 1931 in the context of the similar Thurstone model.)

I would like to apply the Bradley-Terry model with rank-breaking, even though other models are available, because in general these models are either not implemented fully in R, have restrictive assumptions, or cannot deal with a large number of ranked items.

The problem, as I understand it, is that the Bradley-Terry model assumes that each pairwise comparison is an independent observation. But this is not true in the case of rank-breaking. Rankings can only produce transitive data, while if the data were really consisting of independent observations, some portion should be intransitive. So the resulting standard errors and p-values are anti-conservative. For a better explanation of the issues, see this article by Albert Maydeu-Olivares: http://www.ub.edu/gdne/amaydeusp_archivos/amaydeu%20imps2001.pdf

It is not difficult to get correct p-values using a permutational method. The original data can be permuted randomly as rankings (not allowing intransitivity to arise), then undergo rank-breaking and provide a valid distribution under the null model of the p-values.

But my question is how to obtain correct standard errors and p-values, using an analytical method implemented in R.

What follows is a reproducible example using the salad dataset from the prefmod package.

```
library(prefmod)
library(BradleyTerry2)

# Define function that does rank-breaking; suggestions to speed this up are welcome!
rankbreak <- function(x, rank = TRUE){

  n <- ncol(x)
  cc <- combn(n, 2)
  cc <- t(cbind(cc,rbind(cc[2,],cc[1,])))
  r <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=n)
  rr <- r
  colnames(r) <- colnames(x)
  rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
  if(rank){x <- t(apply(x, 1, function(x) order(x, decreasing=TRUE)))}
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){

    r0 <- rr
    v <- x[i,cc[,1]] > x[i,cc[,2]] 
    r0[cc] <- v
    r <- r + r0

  }

  return(r)

}


# fit of Critchlov & Fligner (1991) Salad Dressings Data
# using BT model with rank-breaking
salad_rb <- rankbreak(salad)
salad_bn <- countsToBinomial(salad_rb)
summary(BTm(cbind(win1, win2), player1, player2, data = salad_bn))
```

This gives the following result:

```
Call: BTm(outcome = cbind(win1, win2), player1 = player1, player2 = player2, 
    data = salad_bn)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6  
 1.0818   0.2381  -1.1220   0.4101   0.5344   0.6499  

Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)      
..B   1.5585     0.2973   5.242 1.59e-07 *** 
..C   1.1966     0.2851   4.198 2.70e-05 *** 
..D   0.5095     0.2742   1.858   0.0632 .
--- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 42.1804  on 6  degrees of freedom Residual deviance:  3.3621  on 3
degrees of freedom 
AIC: 31.549

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The permutational approach to estimate the p-values (using 9999 permutations) gave these corrected p-values:

```
..B     ..C     ..D 
0.00003 0.00057 0.13600
```

As expected, these p-values are higher than in the Bradley-Terry model, demonstrating that it produces anti-conservative p-values in this case. An additional problem is that the first p-value (..B) would need even more than 9999 permutations to be estimated with acceptable accuracy! (And accurate p-values are needed if we want to correct for multiple testing.) The permutational approach requires a lot of computational power, even with this small dataset. The permutations are easy to parallelize, but I think I would be wasting a lot of resources if an analytical solution were available.

I wonder if existing solutions similar to those for clustered standard errors in regression analysis apply to this problem. Or if any of the solutions described by Maydeu-Olivares in the article referenced above would be available in R.

To summarize, the solution I am looking for...

- produces correct p-values and SEs for the Bradley-Terry model with
  rank-breaking;
- uses an analytical / not computationally-intensive
  method;
- is implemented in R (or can be implemented);
- works with datasets with a large number of items being compared.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is better to use a Plackett-Luce model. In other communication, David Firth pointed out that the Bradley-Terry model with rank-breaking is not correct from a statistical point of view.

To solve this issue, Heather Turner is now implementing the Placket-Luce model in R, see here: https://github.com/hturner/PlackettLuce